# WPF: open a window in maximized state from the start

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to open a window in WPF that is already maximized as soon as it is visible.

I tried the obvious:

```
<Window Title="My window" WindowState="Maximized" ...>
    ...
</Window>
```

however, if I do this the window doesn't open maximized. It opens at its default size and then, half a second later, gets maximized. Is there a way to bypass this and open the window maximized from the start?

EDIT: not a duplicate of the linked question, I'm doing it the same way as the accepted answer there. My problem isn't that it doesn't work, the problem is that it doesn't work "fast enough": with that solution the window opens not maximized and then gets maximized a split second later. I want to know if there's a way to open it ALREADY maximized.

Comment: Hello, I can't seem to reproduce the problem as in my case the window automatically opens maximized with the same code.

Comment: @Sasinosoft: weirdly, setting it in code (see accepted answer) makes it open immediately, while setting it in XAML takes a few milliseconds before maximizing.... I don't understand why, I thought the XAML would be translated by the compilare into C# code equivalent to the one posteb by Explorer, weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you open the window ?

Try this.

```
win1 = new Window1();
win1.Show();
win1.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason setting it like that (in code) seems "faster" than using the XAML attribute... with the XAML attribute it takes a split second to maximize after showing, in code it's almost immediate. Weird, I would have thought the two things would've been equivalent....